# Criar modal com o conteúdo da tag Code

Tags: javascript, html, modal

Estou desenvolvendo um trabalho para a faculdade e pra apresentar fiz uma página simples em html.

A página possuí uma div com a tag code, onde eu jogo um arquivo json com mais mil linhas.

Eu gostaria de criar um modal que ocupe a tela toda e dentro dele conteúdo da tag code. Seria como expandir para uma melhor visualização.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pq não usa um modal do Bootstrap por exemplo?

Comment: Aqui no site te vários modelos de modal, uns com jquery outros js puro e uns ate 100% com CSS, basta vá pesquisar melhor que vc encontra

Comment: Veja se isso serve http://kithomepage.com/sos/modal-resize.htm#normalModal

Comment: Aqui tem um modal só com css https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269780/n%C3%A3o-consigo-criar-um-modal-com-html/269796#269796

Comment: Tenho pouco conhecimento com HTML, tentei e nenhum deu certo. Mesmo assim obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @LeAndrade pq estou usando outro css e o bootstrap vai alterar todo o estilo