# É possível fazer a customização de um alert?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, alert

Entre um if e else tenho uma chamada de um alert para retornar uma resposta para o usuário, entre tando o layout do alert em si não fica muito de acordo com o layout do site, gostaria de saber como posso personalizar isso.

```
if(ainput5 == false || ainput4 == false || ainput3 == false || ainput2 == false || ainput == false){
    alert('Para finalizar a compra é necessario informar a quantidade de salgados.');
    document.formMonteCaixa.creditCard5.focus();
  }
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Customizar o alert](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/267905/customizar-o-alert)

Comment: Visite o [Sweet Alert](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#getting-started). Tem bastantes usos e costumizações para os `alerts`.

Comment: Acredito que o melhor que você pode fazer é utilizar o sweetalert. É um componente pronto, entretanto extremamente  agradável.

Comment: Irei dar uma olhada nesse Sweet Alert

Comment: Testei aqui, acredito que seja a melhor opção mesmo facilitou muito mais meu trabalho, obrigado pela dica !

Answer (score 1):

Breve resposta: **Não**

O alert do navegador é um simples alerta DOM, como descrito na W3C "mostrar um alerta ao usuário e esperar para que ele o feche"; via de regra: não há especificação, embora navegadores até possam deixar você personalizar como fazem com a scrool bar: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar mas isto estaria fora da especificação

## Como personalizar (Alternativa simples)

Você precisa fazer seu próprio alert e imitar o comportamento do navegador por javascript.

exemplo:

## JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function customAlert(message) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.classList.add("custom-alert");
        var close = document.createElement("a");
        close.textContent = "[x]";
        close.classList.add("close"); // para o seu css
        close.addEventListener("click", () => {
            document.body.removeChild(div);
        }, true);
        div.appendChild(close);
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }

    customAlert("ola");
</script>
```

## CSS

```
.custom-alert {
    /* o css do seu alerta */
}
```

W3C dom alert: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-alert

Comment: Aceito sugestões para melhorar a resposta, este é uma questão bem comum entre desenvolvedores web

Comment: Uma duvida e para fechar esse alert? criaria algo para dar um display nele?

Comment: para fechar o alert, você pode inserir uma tag "a" ou "button" (por exemplo) e adicionar um evento à ela, no clique você remove o elemento do body

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso o sweetalert, muito simples e fácil de usar. Da uma olhada na documentação [aqui](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/).