# Como usar uma imagem em uma caixa de alerta em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, alert

Aqui eu tenho um simples código em JavaScript:

```
window.alert("iae");
```

quando esta caixa de alerta é exibida eu queria que tivesse uma imagem dentro da caixa de alerta já vi isso em muitos sites mais não sei como faz.

Comment: Talvez ajude-o https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/267911/99718

Comment: esse tipo de coisa não esta em foco atualmente, onde todos falamos de Componentes, mas a titulo de estudo e curiosidade, vc pode dar uma olhada no assunto usando Jquery, nesse link: [ alertas em Jquery](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)! apesar de não estar no Hype, o Jquery ainda esta espalhado ai por todo lugar. espero que ajude.
abraço!

Comment: Isso não pode ser feito, conforme respondido pelo @Maniero. Caso você queira algo para apresentar uma mensagem com a possibilidade de adicionar uma imagem, você deve seguir a sugestão do ***Marcio Alexandre*** ou do ***Valdeir Psr*** e utilizar uma "Janela Modal".

Answer (score 5):

Não pode. Não foi feito para isso, foi feito para dar um alerta rápido e simples. Na verdade, quase sempre o seu uso está errado e é praticamente considerado obsoleto (não deveria ser muito usado em aplicações modernas que não sejam muito triviais).

A solução em que se usa seria uma camada de conteúdo que monta o modal de alerta do jeito que quiser, eventualmente usar algum componente pronto mais moderno, e aí pode colocar imagem ou o que desejar, embora provavelmente seja um abuso usar uma imagem em uma alerta, exceto uma de indicação se aquilo é só uma informação, um aviso ou erro. Mas personalizar o alerta padrão do navegador não é possível.

> [Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md)

.

Answer (score 2):

O `alert()` é muito limitado e pouco utilizado atualmente. Com ele não é possível formatar e muito menos incluir uma imagem.

A melhor forma é utilizar algum componente de JavaScript mais rico:

```js
$( function() {
  $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Ok: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    }
  });
} );
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="dialog-message" title="Download complete">
    <p>
      <img src="minhaimagem.png">
      A sua mensagem a ser apresentada no box. Aqui você pode <b>formatar</b>.
    </p>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Fonte: [jQuery-UI: dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog)